# Verify whether $V = \textrm{null}P \oplus \textrm{range}T$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Verify whether $V = \textrm{null}T \oplus \textrm{range}T$

Define $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ as $$T(z_1, z_2) = (-z_2, z_1)$$

To show that $\textrm{null}T + \textrm{range}T$ is a direct sum, it is enough to show that $\textrm{null}T \cap \textrm{range}T = \{0\}$. Since any vector in $\textrm{null}$T is of the form $Tv = 0$, we just need to show that $v \in \textrm{range}T = 0$ too.

Consider the basis of $T$, $(0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$. $v \in \textrm{range}T = 0$ can be written as the linear combination $$v = a_1(0,1) + a_2(-1,0)$$

Since these vectors are a basis, they are linearly independent. Thus $a_1 = a_2 = 0$ so $$v = a_1(0,1) + a_2(-1,0) = 0$$ as desired.

Is my proof correct and also accurate in showing $V = \textrm{null}T \oplus \textrm{range}T$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in\operatorname{null}(\textsf{T})\cap\operatorname{range}(\textsf{T})$. We need to show that $x=\mathbf 0$.

Since $x\in\operatorname{null}(\textsf{T})$, this means that $\textsf{T}(x)=\mathbf 0$. Also, since $x\in\operatorname{range}(\textsf{T})$, there exists $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x=\textsf{T}(y)$. Now, apply $\textsf T$ in the last equation and we see that

$$\mathbf{0}=\textsf{T}(x)=\textsf{T}(\textsf{T}(y))=\textsf{T}^2(y)$$

but $\textsf{T}^2=-\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$, meaning that $\mathbf{0}=\textsf{T}^2(y)=-y$, and then, $y=\mathbf 0$. Thus

$$x=\textsf{T}(y)=\textsf{T}(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf 0$$

as we want to prove.

Let me add some comments on why your proof is not correct.  To get started, each vector in $\ker(\textsf T)$ is not "in the form of $Tv=0$". Each vector $v$ in $\ker(\textsf T)$ *satisfies* that $\textsf{T}(v)=\mathbf 0$, so, you cannot conclude that it is enough to show that $\operatorname{range}(\textsf T)=\{\mathbf 0\}$.

Also, if you have $v=a_1(0,1)+a_2(-1,0)$ you cannot arrive to say that $a_1=a_2=0$, *unless* $v$ is the zero vector, this is by the definition of linear independence.